# Git users in an SVN shop, organising our repos

Tags: git, git-svn

I work in an SVN shop, but to inject a bit of sanity in my work I use git-svn. A growing number of my colleagues are seeing the light as well, and now we'd like to, in some cases completely side-step SVN.  Currently we each have our own git-svn repo, but due to wildly differing hashes we can't really share anything except plain patches or via SVN.  How should we organise our repos in order to allow direct sharing (via git-remote)?

The only way I can come up with is a single, shared git-svn repo, which we use as a gateway to SVN, but that'd probably be a bit cumbersome to work with--it'd be much better if we all could push to SVN directly from our own git-svn repos.

**Edit:** Unfortunately I don't have admin access to the SVN server, so solutions like *subgit* are of little use at the moment, even though they are of interest.

Comment: Sounds like you need to inject *a lot* of sanity into management and convince them to use git everywhere, and eliminate this sneakernet of Git upstart rebels. If there's a high-up guy called Darth Subvertus who *insists* on using Subversion, then you need to become Luke Gitwalker and cut off his arm (after he cuts off yours).

Comment: Haha, yes, if it only were that easy.  My main opponents have just recently been convinced that SVN actually is a step up from CVS, getting them to wrap their brains around Git will be a very difficult task indeed.  Furthermore, their office is 300 km away, well outside the reach of a normal lightsabre.

Comment: @allquixotic That's some pretty hard trolling. Subversion works just fine for non-distributed teams and while Git might be "better", you're looking at [2-6 weeks for your developers to get up to speed on Git](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/atlassian-svn-to-git-migration-human-side/). If you have a lot of developers, that might be a lot of wasted time and money and might even introduce bugs.

Comment: That's exactly why it's useful to switch the developers one at a time as they grow to it. Though some high profile projects like KDE have switched in a big bang and it seems to have worked for them just fine (the conversion tool they used is not bidirectional; hm, and it's not necessary).

Comment: @ta.speot.is That's exactly why you should use git-svn or subgit in such a situation, so that the transition is smooth. Atlassian did that if I remember correctly, there is a nice writeup on their migration on the web.

Comment: @AdamAdamaszek: No, Atlassian didn't have transition period. They seem to have done a big bang change – all changes through subversion until some moment and all commits through git afterwards.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: that's right: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/01/moving-confluence-from-subversion-to-git/

Comment: @Magnus: did you find any OSS alternatives to subgit?

Comment: @AdamAdamszek I didn't look.  I imagine any subgit alternative would also require being installed on the SVN server itself.  Getting the administrator of that Windows box to install subgit, or an alternative, is a much larger (political) project than I'd like to take on at the moment.

Comment: Any full-fledged one perhaps would require svn install. I truly recommend a simple script-based solution - it's simple, works beatifully, and having full control over it also helps.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that SubGit 2.0 (http://subgit.com/2.0) doesn't require Subversion server access and could be used to build a mirror of a remote Subversion repository. Disclaimer: I'm a SubGit developer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may look at [subgit](http://subgit.com/):

> SubGit is tool for a smooth, stress-free Svn to Git migration. Install it once on the server side and use both Subversion and Git as long as you like.
>
> SubGit lets one to set up a bidirectional Subversion to Git replication (writable mirror).

And:

> SubGit is a solution for a company-wide migration from Svn to Git that is:
>
> ```
> Much better than git-svn (see comparison);
> Requires no changes of the infrastructure that is already in place;
> Allows one to use all Git and all Subversion features;
> Provides genuine stress-free migration experience.
> ```

Comment: Yes, indeed, that would fit the bill perfectly.  Now I just need to find some way to carry us over until I've cajoled the system admin to install subgit on the SVN server.

Comment: One thing worth adding is that SubGit 2.0 (http://subgit.com/2.0) doesn't require Subversion server access and could be used to build a mirror of a remote Subversion repository. Disclaimer: I'm a SubGit developer.

Answer (score 1):

> it'd be much better if we all could push to SVN directly from our own git-svn repos.

Isn't the what `git svn dcommit` command is for?

Use `git svn rebase` to rebase your git clone to the central svn repo, then `git svn dcommit` to push your local commits to svn.

I use git svn every day with the [GCC git mirror](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror#Commit_upstream_.28git-svn.29) and it works very well. Maybe that's because there's a central read-only mirror, that gets updated automatically from svn commits, so everyone using git-svn sees the same history from the git mirror and the same set of commit-ids. That allows fetching and merging from the read-only mirror, then just to a git svn rebase and git svn dcommit to push changes to the svn repo. Those changes then get sync'd to the read-only mirror and fetched by everyone else, with the same IDs.

Comment: The problem is that the conversion from svn to git depends on external factors beyond the subversion repository itself. So two git-svn imports of the same repository have _different_ git commit ids for the same subversion repositories and thus you can't share git revisions between them.

Comment: I.e. -1, does not address the question at all.

Comment: I use `git svn` every day with the [GCC git mirror](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror#Commit_upstream_.28git-svn.29) and it works very well. Maybe that's because there's a central read-only mirror, that gets updated automatically from svn commits, so everyone using svn-git sees the same history from the git mirror and the same set of commit-ids. That allows fetching and merging from the read-only mirror, then just to a `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit` to push changes to the svn repo. Those changes then get sync'd to the read-only mirror and fetched by everyone else, with the same IDs

Comment: Jonathan, the interesting bit for me would be if you, with this setup, also can share work directly between the git users.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Can you please add description of that into the _answer_? Thanks.

Comment: Having read the link in the comment it sounds like a workable, but not very good approach as it creates heaps of merges.

Comment: @JanHudec, what merges? There are no merge commits in the upstream svn history (at least not due to git-svn users, there might be some unrealted ones done with svn merge)

Comment: When I do a commit with `git svn dcommit` and then wait for it to be sync'd to the git mirror, then do a `git pull` I do not get a merge from `origin`, I get a fast-forward, implying that my local commit that I pushed and the one in the Git mirror created by sync'ing from svn are the same commit. For this to work I have to `git svn rebase` before committing, but as I understand it that's how you're meant to use git-svn anyway

Comment: @Magnus, I don't share with other git users, I only publish work by pushing to svn, but I don't see why I couldn't add remotes for other git users (I actually do that between two local clones of the git mirror.) The `git svn rebase` step would rewrite history on `master`, so you couldn't collaborate on your local `master` branches easily, but if you each have an integration branch in your local repo which never gets rebased, and you pull from each other's integration branches, it should work OK

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I believe there is some setting of git svn that affects whether the other import may be exactly equivalent or not. It may always happen it won't be, (e.g. you can dcommit a merge and the other repo does not know it was a merge so it can't make it the same).

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's when it comes to sharing between git users that we've run into problems.  We both make sure to keep a linear history, using *rebase* frequently, but that hasn't prevented our *git-svn* repos from having no single hash in common.

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional gatewaying between two different version control systems predates git by ages. I have already been doing it by hand between CVS and Arch some 10 years ago. If you don't want to buy subgit, you can maintain the gateway manually or even try to script it. The workflow is simple:

- Have two branches, `trunk` and `master`. `trunk` mirrors subversion, `master` is plus the changes developed in git
- Whenever there is new change in subversion:

  1. `$ git svn fetch`
  2. `master$ git merge trunk`
- Whenever trunk is pushed:

  1. `trunk$ git merge master`
  2. `trunk$ git svn dcommit`
  3. `master$ git merge trunk`
- You should do both sequences atomically, i.e. only one operation at a time.
- You may consider setting git-svn up so it does *not* rewrite the commits with the subversion revision info to reduce the number of merge commits in git.
- It can be done for multiple branches, but I don't think merging separate subversion branches in git could work.

Answer (score 1):

We are in exactly the same situation. What we have is (warning, some pseudo-code!):

- remote git repo, scripted (using bash scripts), cannot be --bare
- a pre-receive hook that checks the username, then per each ref received and for all SVN-mapped branches: (git -> svn):

  - `git checkout -f <branch>`
  - `git reset HEAD --hard`
  - `git clean -fdx`
  - `git merge -n $newrev`
  - `git svn dcommit`
  - if failed, revert all,
  - then, after all loops - update all SVN branches (using the script, see below)
- a cronjob updating git-svn branches with latest svn changes (svn -> git):

  - `git checkout --orphan svn-update <random-branch-name>`
  - `git svn fetch --all`
  - for all git-svn branches: `git branch -D <branch> && git branch --track <svn-branch> refs/remotes/<svn-branch>`,
- ssh keys for git authentication
- users-managed SVN authentication (based on git usernames, this will depend on your setup)

This way no one uses SVN directly and the only difference vs pure git is you cannot change git-svn branches history (as SVN will not let you dcommit that).

Comment: Did you perform this scripting yourselves, or is there an OSS project to base it on?

Comment: We've tried a couple of OSS available options, but none of them satisfied our needs, so it's all based on our in-house written .bash scripts. I can't paste nor OSS them, but let me update the answer with some details...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar setup, and here's a process that worked for me and the folk I work with:

1. One person creates a Git repository using `git svn clone` and friends.
2. Everyone else clones that first Git repository using regular Git commands, then copies the `svn-remote.{name}` bits of the first repository's `.git/config`.  There's instructions for doing this in the examples in `git help svn`.

Now, everyone has a `git-svn` setup that can be used to interact with the Subversion repository.

More importantly, everyone has a `git-svn` setup with the same branches and commit history, which means the commits that `git svn fetch` and friends create will be identical, *including the hashes*. At that point, as well as pushing and pulling to the Subversion repository, you can use all Git's fancier distributed features amongst yourselves.

Unlike with regular Git, you do need to be careful about sharing config – if your branch structure diverges, your hashes will diverge too. Occasionally things will go wrong and need fixing up (I once had two `git svn fetch`es going on at once, which clobbered each others work in a subtle way; I had to rewind my history with `git svn reset` and refetch in order to keep my hashes matching other people's). But them's the restrictions of mashing the two tools together.